# Why does my LCD screen display white rectangles?

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd

I recently got an Arduino LCD screen. I tried connecting it to the UNO with the 10k potentiometer and all the needed equipment but all I got were white rectangles instead of characters. I have uploaded the hello world code but I saw no changes.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you may have the contrast set (or wired) wrong.

Comment: Or you have drawn white rectangles to the screen.

Answer (score 2):

As @Majenko already mentioned, you have to set the right contrast. Use potentiometer to find out what value suits you right.